# Do we actually know the compiler behavior when a variable is declared in a loop?

Tags: javascript, memory, ecmascript-6

Most of the questions on this topic are pretty old and are actually referring to ES5. Most of the suggested standards are based on the assumption that we only deal with function scope (And it's more readable to declare inside a loop). ES6 brings block scoped variable types, so I believe this question is worth resurfacing. Also no one has confirmed what the compiler behavior may be (from what I've researched), so this is still an open question in my mind.

Consider the following sample code block for reference in this issue:

```js
function foo(array) {
    const dictionary = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    let currentElement;

    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        currentElement = (dictionary[array[i]]) ? someObj.foo : null;
    }
}

// versus

function foo(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        const dictionary = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        let currentElement = (dictionary[array[i]]) ? someObj.foo : null;
    }
}
```

**So the question**: What is the browser behavior? Do we know that modern browsers actually do re-use variable declarations within loops, and to what capacity? Do any of the browsers re-allocate and garbage collect variables in loops? Any comment in other questions in regards to these topics have been assumptions with no proof.

---

As far as the argument that any performance gained regarding this topic is negligible, and we should declare inside the loop:

Why?

I think of it as this way:

Why worry about optimizing prematurely when this "optimization" costs you nothing. Using it as a standard can only help you in the long run. If someone offers me two apples, and one has a 5% chance of being bad, I would take the "good" one.

Comment: Your thinking is reasonable. Also — unless you are certain of which JS VMs your code is compiled by (e.g. V8 vs JavaScriptCore vs SpiderMonkey, etc.) — then you can't be certain of how these optimizations might or might not take place. But you can guarantee that a variable is created once outside a loop (instead of potentially every time inside the loop) by declaring it in that position (rather than relying on compiler behavior). (1/2)

Comment: It's almost never something to worry about while creating the initial logic (pre-optimizations can destroy productivity by derailing focus), and something that you will (hopefully naturally) develop better habits about as you continue to write software (e.g. through code review, experience, etc.). This is something to measure in perf testing afterward and then optimize in a refactor if the data shows that its warranted. Remember: ["make it work, make it right, make it fast"](https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast) (2/2)

Comment: Does this have any bearing on your application?